# Silverstripe CMS gives File size zero error

Tags: error-handling, content-management-system, silverstripe

I have designed a page that has upload attachments ... one image and another PDF.
The data is created in the database, however, when trying to upload a file of either type I get a server error "File Size is zero bytes".
A search of this forum yielded entries that indicate it is a permission issue of site assets folder or assets/Uploads folder. I have checked both and the permissions are correct. 
The search on other platforms seems to indicate file size issues are from the PHP5.6 php.ini file settings. Both are correct and set to a value well above the 8Mb default.
The Apache2 log looks like:

```
[Tue Jun 06 15:11:57.167558 2017] [:error] [pid 26971] [client 192.168.1.73:50192] PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/html/ss/framework/filesystem/Filesystem.php on line 53, referer: http://192.168.1.70/ss/index.php/admin/pages/edit/show/23
[Tue Jun 06 15:11:57.170810 2017] [:error] [pid 26971] [client 192.168.1.73:50192] PHP Warning:  copy(/var/www/html/ss/assets/Uploads/news-attachments/the-satern-ring.pdf): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/ss/framework/filesystem/Upload.php on line 207, referer: http://192.168.1.70/ss/index.php/admin/pages/edit/show/23
```

This code also seems to indicate a permission issue. The folders all have the owner as root group as root and drw-rw----, files can be uploaded manually but not through the CMS.

So where do I look now?

Environment:
SS v3.6.0 theme bootstrap
OS Linux Mint 18.1
Apache 2.4 PHP 5.6

Comment: `The folders all have the owner as root group as root`: Unless your web server is running as root, you'll need to `chown` the folders to a user/group that the web server's user (e.g. `apache` or `nginx`) can access. If they're owned by root it's unlikely that those users will have the access they need.

Comment: Understood. However, that permissions arrangement is what produced this problem. As stated in the original post all folders are owned by root and in the group root. The only user at this point is the default admin user in the CMS. I think there is another problem that is not so obvious.

Answer (score 2):

This can occur when framework does not have permission to write files to the server. If this is the case, when we upload images through the CMS the file can not be written to assets and the CMS returns a  `"File size zero error"`. The website also cannot combine files (such as JavaScript and CSS files) and cannot create new resampled images.

To help investigate this problem we can run the SilverStripe install wizard. The install wizard will notify us of issues preventing SilverStripe from running correctly.

To run the install wizard we visit http://www.example.com/install.php

The `install.php` is usually deleted after the site is installed, so if it is missing we will need to replace it. We can download the file from github. Here is the `install.php` file for SilverStripe 3.6: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-installer/blob/3.6/install.php

Once downloaded we upload this to the root directory of our webserver. Once this is done we can visit the `install.php` URL.

Here is a screenshot showing an example of the file permission issue warnings that the install wizard outputs:

[image: SilverStripe install wizard screenshot showing file permission errors]

What we want to do now is fix up all the warnings that the install wizard is reporting.

If this is a shared hosting environment we might not have the ability to fix these issues ourselves. In this case we should be able to send the `install.php` link to hosting support asking them fix the issues.

Once all the issues are fixed the site should work correctly. Make sure to delete the `install.php` when we are done.

Comment: 3dgoo Thank you.

I think I covered this in a previous post. The install did not show any permission issues on install. I would have corrected those before being able to use the CMS.

i have tried a number of things in a trial and error effort to find a solution - including changing the owner/group to the same as the web server (www-data)...did not change the result.

The default admin is the only user at this point and the CMS performs all other functions. New pages are created and manual uploads are possible outside the CMS. It is only within the CMS this problem exists.

Comment: What you are describing sounds the same as an issue I had on a client's website last week. The problem in my case was the file owner set for the web server was incorrect causing SilverStripe not to have permissions to edit any files. This was caused by the web hosting suddenly changing the the server settings after the site was working correctly for years. If you haven't checked the `install.php` since you have noticed these problems, I would suggest uploading the file and checking if it reports any issues.

Comment: Well this is not exactly the same. All other functions of the CMS work fine. I can create and edit documents such as news and new pages. They are stored on the database...not the file system. It seems to only affect file system storage as in the case of uploaded images and documents in the assets folder. And in a particular way. The details are all there in the previous post.

Comment: When I say `"SilverStripe did not have permissions to edit any files"` I mean any file system files. SilverStripe could still work with the database. So it could still create, edit and delete pages and data in the CMS. It just could not write any files to the file system.